# Significant gas cost difference between store data in initial variable and change data

Tags: solidity, gas

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0-only
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;

// when SAVE == address(0) call setSave execution cost 22622 gas
// when SAVE != address(0) call setSave execution cost 5522 gas
contract test {
    address public SAVE;

    function setSave(address save) public {
        SAVE = save;
    }
}
```

Storing new data in an initial variable and changing data in a variable that already had data were different gas costs.It's a big difference, and I'm trying to figure out why. I'm looking for advice on that.

Additionally, is there a good tool to see the Opcode of a smart contract call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This gas difference is described in the [Ethereum yellow paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf)'s *Appendix G. Fee Schedule* (page 27):

> | Name | Value | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | G<sub>sset</sub> | 20000 | Paid for an `SSTORE` operation when the storage value is set to non-zero from zero. |
> | G<sub>sreset</sub> | 2900 | Paid for an `SSTORE` operation when the storage value’s zeroness remains unchanged or is set to zero. |

The reason for this large difference in gas fee is to reflect the additional computational cost of storing new account data.

A common gas optimization trick is to initialize variables to non-zero values during deployment to pay this fee upfront, then only switch the variables between non-zero variables. For example, OpenZeppelin's [`ReentrancyGuard.sol`](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/release-v4.9/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol) smart contract flips the reentrancy guard variable between `1` and `2` instead of `0` and `1` for this exact reason:

```
    // The values being non-zero value makes deployment a bit more expensive,
    // but in exchange the refund on every call to nonReentrant will be lower in
    // amount. [...]
```

> Additionally, is there a good tool to see the Opcode of a smart contract call?

If you mean to view all the opcodes executed in a transaction, [geth](https://geth.ethereum.org/) has functionality to output a transaction trace: [EVM Tracing](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/developers/evm-tracing). Etherscan also has this trace functionality built-in to its online transaction viewer (on any transaction page, click `More > Geth Debug Trace` on the right side).

Comment: Thank you, that was a perfect answer!!